# Correct Usage of >> in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, typeerror, monads, ghci

Just now being introduced to monads in Haskell and hit something of a roadblock with `>>`.

`>>=` makes sense to me, as I can get the following out of Prelude:

```
Prelude> Just 1 >>= (\ x -> Just (x+1))
Just 2
```

My understanding is that `>>` is the same as bind, but only used when the function is constant with regards to its parameter. But when I try to do that in Prelude:

```
Prelude> Just 1 >> (\_ -> Just 10)

<interactive>:7:12: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe b’
              with actual type ‘t0 -> Maybe Integer’
• The lambda expression ‘\ _ -> Just 10’ has one argument,
  but its type ‘Maybe b’ has none
  In the second argument of ‘(>>)’, namely ‘(\ _ -> Just 10)’
  In the expression: Just 1 >> (\ _ -> Just 10)
• Relevant bindings include
    it :: Maybe b (bound at <interactive>:7:1)
```

I'm very much struggling to decipher this error message... can anyone help with proper usage of `>>`? And what am I not understanding about it?

Comment: Well since `>>` already factors out that `\_ ->` you do not have to write it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(>>=)` has type `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. In your example `m` is `Maybe` so you provide a `Maybe Int` and a function `Int -> Maybe Int`.

`(>>)` has type `Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b` so you need to pass a `Maybe b` instead of a function which returns a `Maybe b` e.g.

```
Just 1 >> Just 10
```

In this case this is the same as `Just 10` however if the first value is `Nothing` the result will also be `Nothing`:

```
Nothing >> Just 10
```

You will usually use `(>>)` if the first value represents some effect you want to perform and ignore the result e.g `IO`.

```
putStrLn "Hello world" >> pure 10 :: IO Int
```

or `State`:

```
put "state" >> pure 10 :: State String Int
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Sorry if this is needing a full question in itself, but what exactly does this achieve then? What purpose does `Just 1 >> Just 10` serve that just `Just 10` doesn't?

Comment: @TheHelpfulBees, `Maybe` is probably not the best example for thinking about `>>`. You might get more out of thinking about what it does for `State s`, `Writer w`, or `IO`. Once you understand the pattern, you'll be able to see that it applies in a fairly uninteresting way to `Either a`, its duller cousin `Maybe`, and even more trivially to `Reader e` and `Identity`.